# Steps on how can i run valac in windows

Tags: vala

I just wanna ask what are the steps to create and compile codes in vala?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any steps for "create".  Just write code your preferred editor.  If you don't already know Vala you should probably start by reading the [tutorial](http://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/Tutorial).

The best way to run Vala on Windows these days is probably with [tarnyko's package](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/35).  There aren't really any steps for that either... once it's installed, you can run it from the command line just like on other operating systems.